# How can I determine duplicate entries with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to determine if the last 15 entries in my DB are duplicates.  Is there an easy way to do this with MySQL or do I need to iterate through each result and compare it to the previous one some how?

My sql query looks like this:

```
SELECT content FROM `messages` WHERE sender_id = 12345 order by date desc limit 10
```

In this case the results look like this:

```
test1
test1
test2
test1
test1
test1
test1
test2
test1
test1
```

I would expect to see 80% the same in this case.

Any thoughts or suggestions how I could accomplish this easily with SQL and PHP?

Comment: What is your overall intent? Do you want to strip out dupes, prevent them, count them?

Comment: My intent is to flag users entering 90% duplicate content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first try couting how many times each entry is present, using `count()` and a `goup by` clause :

```
select content, count(content)
from messages
WHERE sender_id = 12345
    -- maybe add a condition on the date, here
group by content
having count(content) > 1
```

Then, for each content that is returned by this query, you'll want to do something *(if you try deleting some entries, make sure to not delete all of them, and keep the first or last one)*

Comment: Glad I could help ; have fun !

Answer (score 0):

You can see the number of duplicates like this:

```
select content, count(content) 
from `messages` 
WHERE sender_id = 12345 
group by content
order by count(content) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

if count is greater that 1 its duplicate.

```
 SELECT  count(content)  FROM `messages` WHERE sender_id = 12345  group by content order by date desc limit 10
```